# Embedded ApacheDS 2.0 doesn't have ou=config

Tags: ldap, apacheds

I have succeeded in getting an embedded ApacheDS instance to start with a Java Web App thanks to the example found [here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/directory/sandbox/kayyagari/embedded-sample-trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/directory/seserver/EmbeddedADSVerTrunk.java), and have added partitions to it. The problem is that the resulting LDAP server instance doesn't show 'ou=config'. Any idea why or what I can do to to get this important element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In embedded mode you configure the server programmatically, ou=config is for configuring the server running in network mode.